# sortable - items changes top margin while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Why top and/or bottom margin of `child` is changed while dragging them?
I need them to stay inline.

```js
$('.parent').sortable({
 containment: "parent",
 axis: "x",
});
```

```css
.parent{
text-align:center;
}

.child{
display:inline-block;
padding:2px 9px;
border-radius:9px;
background:gold;
margin:0 9px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='child'>323</div>
<div class='child'>525</div>
<div class='child'>727</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: top;` to `.child`

```js
$('.parent').sortable({
 containment: "parent",
 axis: "x",
});
```

```css
.parent{
text-align:center;
}

.child{
display:inline-block;
padding:2px 9px;
border-radius:9px;
background:gold;
margin:0 9px;
cursor:pointer;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='child'>323</div>
<div class='child'>525</div>
<div class='child'>727</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Us this style

```
.parent > div { float: left; margin-left: 10px; background : gold; border-radius : 10px; padding:2px 9px; }
```

```js
$('.parent').sortable({
 containment: "parent",
 axis: "x",
});
```

```css
 .parent > div { float: left; margin-left: 10px; background : gold; border-radius : 10px; padding:2px 9px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='child'>323</div>
<div class='child'>525</div>
<div class='child'>727</div>
</div>
```